# OSB Security, is it worthwhile securing Both the Proxy Service and The Business Service

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

OSB Security, is it worthwhile securing Both the Proxy Service and The Business Service?

Or just the Proxy service?

In other words if the business service is not configured with security, could this be a security hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will link to a couple parts of the documentation for you:

- [9.4 Security and Security Policies for Business Services](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/develop/osb-business-services.htm#OSBDV2177)
- [49.2 Security and Security Policies for Business and Proxy Services](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/develop/osb-security-policies.htm#OSBDV87962)

Now, when you say "if the business service is insecure", you're actually pointing out what needs to be understood.  Can you call a Business Service from a context OUTSIDE of the Proxy Service that you wrote it for?  I would say that there are plenty fo Business Services that you could call from **ANY** Proxy Service in OSB, so if you feel that at the OSB level, you are concerned some developer might code something against your business service and call it without needing to provide some sort of authentication/authorization,  you probbaly will need to secure it.

Furthermore, if you're able to call the Business Service from outside of the box (as you would do with a Proxy Service), then you're likely to face the same sets of concerns as far as letting anyone call that service if they happen to find the URL for it.

This might not be the best answer, but I think your question could use some refining to ask more specifically, "Can Business Services be invoked directly from outside of SBConsole?", which I unfortunately don't have a good answer for you.

I think an even better question is "What vectors can an OSB Business Service be invoked from?"  as it points out WHERE you have to look to ensure that people aren't trying to call your sensitive business services directly.

Comment: Thank you for the complement.  I might not have alluded to this, but I am no OSB expert, so I can't really offer recommendations from the standpoint of a security analyst.  Generally speaking, you need to be aware of the balance between the imposed performance impacts and business needs to secure the data.  It's probably safer to err on the side of securing everything, because only when you start doing it **everywhere** that you can figure out when that level of security might be overkill or unnecessary based on how everything else is used.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, its advisable to secure the proxy service alone. Unlike Proxy Service, business services dont have an endpoint URI to expose them over the internet to other services / proxies. so unless, a developer explicitly "References" his proxy services to the business service that you are using, i dont see any point in securing the business service for wrong use from other proxies, clients.

Please note, for the same reason as mentioned above, we only expose proxies to the external world (clients, other services, etc) and not the business service. Business services are only used to connect to the end systems (legacy systems, other webservices, JMS queues, siebel systems, etc.,)